# Why does my IDE fail to open files?

Tags: arduino-ide-2

I'm using Version: 2.0.3 - Date: 2022-12-05T09:30:25.33 on Windows 10 Pro. Installed under Local user - not for all users.

When I try and open a ino file (either double clicking on a ino file - or file->Open) - it spawns a new window - but then I just see the standard sketch with an empty setup() and loop()

I've uninstalled and re-installed both for my own users and all. But still, it does the same thing. I'm having to open all my sketches in notepad++ and then save them in whatever temp Arduino file it creates. Its hellishly annoying

Comment: 2.0.3 may be broken ... try another version

Comment: Hmm. happening on 2.0.2 too

Comment: And if you run it as "Administrator" ?

Comment: And here https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-2-0-not-starting-up/950998/2 in answer #3 you can start Arduino from CLI and debug it.

Comment: Thanks @MatsK - I think its a bug due to my dodgy filesystem on windows..   I see this in the output

2023-02-21T11:22:21.224Z sketches-service WARN Warning! The request sketch path was different than the response sketch path from the CLI. This could be a potential bug. Request: <\\ace-svr02\Users$\wwade\Documents\GitHub\X80\firmware\x80Tester\x80Tester.ino>, response: <\\ace-svr02\Users$\wwade\Documents\GitHub\X80\firmware\x80Tester>.

Comment: If you try to open a sketch from a shared drive on Windows, it does not work. See the bug [here](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/1797). When opening a sketch fails, IDE returns to a new temp sketch. That's why you see `void setup(){} void loop(){}`.